# Where should I create project folders for node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have Node.js for windows installed the recommended way npm, using the global flag:

```
npm install -g node-windows
```

The next step is to run in your project root:

```
npm link node-windows
```

Do I create the project folder in the directory where I have node.js installed? (C:\Program Files\nodejs)

My Goal is to use node.js to send push notifications. I believe if I create the project directory(folder) in the correct spot all I have to do put the files I want to execute in the project directory and everything should work OK?

Comment: creeate where ever you want, then in console locate folder and just run `node statupscript.js`, that script being what ever script you want

Answer (score 0):

You can create a project folder anywhere. In the commandline you locate your folder:

```
C:\>cd "Users\Me\Documents\NodeJs\Projects\WebServer\"
```

Then just run `node` on any script you wish to startup.

```
C:\Users\Me\Documents\NodeJs\Projects\WebServer\>node startupscript.js
```